# Routing is not working properly in Codeigniter 3x

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was using using this code in old setup of ci and it was working

In routes.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'.'EXT' );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('manya_webpage');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row ){
    $route[ $row->slug ] = 'page/call/'.$row->slug;
}
```

But it is not working in ci setup 3x

```
ERROR 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(/home/content/02/8784902/html/example/system/database/DBEXT) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: config/routes.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DBEXT file is not found. try changing your code to:

```
include(APPPATH.'config/database'.EXT);
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('manya_webpage');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row ){
    $route[ $row->slug ] = 'page/call/'.$row->slug;
}
```

Also make sure that in the index.php you include

```
/ The PHP file extension
// this global constant is deprecated.
define('EXT', '.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the message is about the file

`/home/content/02/8784902/html/example/system/database/DBEXT`

that cannot be found on your system. You should check if your file exists on this path or not and change the path or add the file there.